# Where can I watch Tamako Market?

Tags: resources, tamako-market

I found out the character name to an image I have. He's Yuzuki from *Tamako Market*. I want to watch the anime, but I don't know where to watch it.

I don't really know what websites that have anime to be honest.

Where can I watch Tamako Market?

Comment: This question *is* on-topic provided you're looking for somewhere to watch the show *legally* (i.e. not an illegal streaming/torrenting service). It might be a good idea to take the [tour] and visit the [help] so you can check which kinds of questions are allowed and which aren't. Glad you found the character!

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing where you live, it's not possible to give a definitive answer to where you can legally watch the show, but assuming you're in the US then it *looks*(1) like Tamako Market is available to stream on [Hidive](https://www.hidive.com/tv/tamako-market), for which you can either register an account with them or through VRV. As with most streaming services, it costs money to subscribe but you can get a 30 day free trial to start with. Hidive also runs in other countries, but licensing is a complicated business so it's best if you check for yourself.

If you would rather own a copy, then Tamako Market was licensed by Sentai Filmworks in the US, and they sell the DVD and Blu-Ray on their site or through retailers, although as an older title you may have to search around a bit to find a copy in stock.

(1) I say "looks" because I accessed the site from Australia, so it was probably showing me a different list to what someone in the US would see.

Comment: Just to back up your point about regional availability: I'm from the UK and while I can see Tamako Market on the website, it's not actually available to watch in my country.